# Link subdomain that is CNAME to SendGrid but with CloudFlare enabled ends up on main site

Tags: dns, cname, cloudflare, hsts

We use Cloudflare, and Sendgrid for email.

Via Sendgrid setup, we have added a DNS record:

[image]

However, this redirects to our main domain:
[Example link.construct.net generated by SendGrid](http://link.construct.net/wf/click?upn=Ukp59gY4qC8B0BHJEx7oZDiEp02ijSTHpbz4VhjD5B9JuANLi0jLaBEQ6zEN9tYmE54vEmZrCW1GJmZpv8pSnegQOdir-2BSD9XefFj-2F3aYjZSQ8HC0JQMjsy9EB3aAnRZ_ZglsRIE6P6aE65W2-2F30AL1rNqM7XLE20umx0UuFBXjcj8qSbnWkmGwJIE9o1Eshj5C1xQChtUlfVc2sZu9Nme7t9gcUzZFG6nqv0fWYeOg6HTx-2F78sriJB7BBnI-2BrGbwNHxNL6fSRHgjSDBwRak7kMOvmKSRLqEA8MYvj-2BM3R7DSMyrmvaf8g9OVNA-2BtVoc7XvgEhSZobzwf6ClglxRVWwp98-2BBTjuXcY4YtjohupU4n1LrIcEtiIAMSeGJZIQSgydvBQRyvBlPv70C05SY38Pj0qhjr5uLueCqnwpGDYTLFYRbZSlflpP1FPYJ5no6MkAxJFZJH-2FX-2B8AatY6YOAEpUfTL4ArEXHD5aXICiX4mM0IentVQgyaXBA-2ByMaxmszGjP2BJSaAes-2FkQws-2Frv0vODPUsBgBhkh4NncKw1dQRn7OvdBiDkHdw3KlmuPKket)

If I disable CloudFlare routing (the orange cloud), the URL creates a security exception because HSTS is enabled for `construct.net` and all subdomains.

Am I correct in assuming `link.construct.net` should *not* end up on `construct.net`, and how can I resolve this so that the links resolve correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are incorrect.  An HTTP request to `link.construct.net` should redirect to `construct.net`.

Things are working the way they are supposed to work.  With cloudflare enabled on your link subdomain, the DNS entries for it point to cloudflare.  Cloudflare handles HTTPS termination [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762078/fix-broken-link-tracking-due-to-hsts-on-subdomain). Cloudflare reverse proxies the request to sendgrid.  Sendgrid sends a HTTP 302 temporary redirect to your main site with tracking parameters on the URL.

The redirect to your live site is only for tracking.   The click hits sendgrids servers so that they know about it.   They also use append `utm` tracking parameters onto the URL for your benefit in Google Analytics.